# How to prevent form submit, when focus is on specific input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How I can prevent form submit in JS/jQuery when one field has a focus on it, while retaining normal behaviour on all other input fields?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#formID').on('submit', function(){
    if ($('input:focus').length){return false;}
});
```

This is assuming you try to submit the form without click. Because when you click to submit, the input has a blur event and looses focus.

Else: then [jcubic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18381194/2256325)'s answer might be what you need.

Comment: I think it should be `!$('input:focus').length` since jquery always return an object even if it's empty.

Comment: @jcubic, good point. Edited, also pointed to your answer in case the submit is via `click`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
var prevent = false;
$('input').focus(function() {
   prevent = true;
}).blur(function() {
   prevent = false;
});

$('form').submit(function() {
   if (prevent) {
      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

reference  [e.preventdefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: It will never submit the form no matter if the input have focus or not.